# Is there a way to use scipy.interpolate to do 1d spline interpolation with boundary conditions specified away from data?

Tags: scipy, spline

There are lots of ways of assembling splines directly from data while specifying derivatives at the boundary but I do not see an easy way to specify derivative constraints *away* from the data. For example

```
np.random.seed(0)
M = 30
x = np.random.rand(M)
x.sort()
y = np.random.rand(M) + (10 * x) ** 2

xx = np.linspace(x.min(), x.max(), 100)  # for plotting

import scipy.interpolate as si
f = si.make_interp_spline(x, y) # ok but how to add derivative conditions away from the x-values?

x_derivs = [-1, 2]
order_derivs = [2, 1]
value_derivs = [0, 1]
```

More generally, is there a built in method to do this or take derivative constraints separate from value constraints?

I think it's just a matter of creating the operator matrix to solve the linear problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer : it's not implemented at the moment.

You can of course modify the scipy source, the relevant part is
https://github.com/scipy/scipy/blob/v1.7.0/scipy/interpolate/_bsplines.py#L1105